# Can I (should I) use my DBClientConnection as a global variable?

Tags: c++, qt, mongodb

- Windows 7 SP1
- MSVS 2010
- MongoDB 2.2.0
- Qt 4.8.4

Writing a single-threaded application. I always pass the DBClientConnection as a reference argument to any function that requires access to MongoDB. Can I use a global variable instead so that I don't have to pass the argument?

This came up when using Qt's QKeyEvent. This is implemented with this prototype:

```
void keyPressEvent(QKeyEvent * key_event);
```

reimplementing:

```
void QWidget::keyPressEvent ( QKeyEvent * event )
```

From which function I want to call a MongoDB function but I do not have access to the DBClientConnection within keyPressEvent. Hence why I'm considering making DBClientConnection a global.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A recommended solution is an abstraction of your database object.

[Here is an explanation of the concept in C#](http://www.remondo.net/repository-pattern-example-csharp/)

But to put it simply in a C++ nutshell, the aim is to define an interface. That's all. `IDatabase` or `IRepository`.

It has more or less the role of a global value as you suggest, but you will hide it into a `Factory`, or `DependencyInjection` mechanism... or a global value like the `Singleton` if you really want.

But it is the concrete `class MyMongoDatabase` that will implement the connection stuffs, and pointing to the real mongoDb that should bother with this pointer. Not the rest of your application. **Above all if it is inside of the GUI like your QWidget::keyPressEvent that you plan to access the database**.

```
class MyMongoDatabase : public IDatabase
{
    private:
        void connect();
        void disconnect();

    public:
        std::vector<Something> query_something(int param);
        void insert(AnOtherThing& thing);
        //.... other crud operations
};
```

In your logic/business code you could only have :

```
IDatabase& database = getDatabase();
std::vector<Something> somethings = database.query_something();
```

And `IDatabase` would expose all the functions that are queries, inserts and other CRUD operations. The idea behind is called 'loose coupling'.

Just look if it's worth the coding. It depends on the number of time you do such things in your application. In general for things as big as database, it's a really good idea.